# Cast massive properties Neo4j

Tags: database, graph, neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

I have a Neo4j relationship with a set of properties: ['PROPERTY1', 'PROPERTY2', PROPERTY3', ...]. I use the method below to cast a string to int.

I should cast all properties into the list from string to int. What is an efficient way to cast massive properties?

```
        CALL apoc.periodic.commit(
        "MATCH ()-[r:RELATED_TO]->()
        WHERE r.PROPERTY1 = toString(r.PROPERTY1)
        WITH r LIMIT $limit 
        set r.PROPERTY1 = toInteger(r.PROPERTY1)                   
        RETURN count(*)", 
        {limit : 5000})
```

Comment: What do you mean with "efficient"? A smarter query without hard-coding each property, or some other way to reduce memory footprint like `periodic.commit` that you already use?

Comment: @Brakebein I mean a smarter query without hard-coding each property

Answer (score 0):

You could pass the list of properties as a parameter and iterate over it with `FOREACH`. Properties can be accessed dynamically ([dynamic property](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/4.2/syntax/expressions/)).

```js
propList: ['PROPERTY1', 'PROPERTY2', 'PROPERTY3']
```

```sql
MATCH ()-[r:RELATED_TO]->()

FOREACH (prop IN $propList |
  SET r[prop] = toInteger(r[prop])
)
```